# Multivariate logit

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, logit

I have n individuals with k possible financial products where they can put a % of their incomes. 
I need to predict for each individual the percentage of income that they allocate in each product.

Is there a way to model concurrently all the k percentages, exitimating also the correlation matrix?

In another work I used a Multivariate probit in Stata (Multivariate probit regression using simulated maximum likelihood, L.Cappellari 2004): it's the same thing that I'd like to have now, but in that case the Y have to be 0 or 1, now I have Y that is a rate between 0 and 1.

Suggestions?

Comment: Which 2004 paper are you referring to?

Comment: It would help if you clarified what exactly it is your trying to model and the data you're using.

Comment: Personally, it's not quite clear to me why you'd use a multivariate logit model for portfolio allocation...

Comment: Given an individual variables I need to extimate his portfolio allocation in each asset. What do you suggest?

Comment: What sort of predictors are you using? Why are you trying to estimate his port. allocation? Are you, in effect, trying to *predict* what the allocation will be?

Comment: My suggestion is that you edit the question--add details, fix spelling & grammar, and make sure it's clear what you're trying to do and what you have to work with (because currently you're post is mildly incoherent).

Comment: I'd add to my question my real purpose: predict for each individual the percentage of income that they allocate in each product

Comment: So you have data with which you can train your model? In other words, have you split your data into two groups--the training set and then the actual test set?

Comment: Again, it would help if you gave more of an indication of what your dataset actually looks like...

Comment: Yes, I would like to split data in 2 groups, one for train, the other to predict

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure, if I understood the description of your problem correctly, that you want to use a fractional multinomial logit model...In Stata Buuis' routine fmlogit will do it...Good luck!